# AngularJS scope as factory listener

Tags: angularjs

I have a factory that just returns a upload helper object. This helper uploads a file to a server and returns the upload-progress to its listeners.
The controllers that get injected the factory are the listeners, by setting a callback-method to the upload-helper.
The controllers get the values but don't update their scope with the new values.

Here's the factory:

```
app.factory("upHelper", function(){

    var uploadHelper = function(){
    }
    uploadHelper.prototype.addFileToUpload = function(file){
           this.file = file;
    }
    uploadHelper.prototype.stopUpload = function(){....}
    uploadHelper.prototype.setListener = function(cb){
        var self = this;  
        cb(self.getStatus());
    } 
    var upHelper= new uploadHelper();

    return self.uploadHelper;
}
```

The controller with factory injection:

```
app.controller("upload", function("upHelper"){
    $scope.file = file;

    $scope.uploadFile = function(file){
        uploadHelper.addFileToUpload($scope.files);
        if(!uploadHelper.running)
              uploadHelper.start():
        uploadHelper.setListener(function(uploadStatus){
               $scope.file.uploadStatus = uploadStatus;    // this doesn't update the scope
               $scope.apply(function(){
                    $scope.file.uploadStatus = uploadStatus;   //causes error and doesn't update anything.
               });


        }
    }
}
```

Several controllers use the uploadHelper .. is there a better way to implement this function, or make this work?

Comment: what's the error? it should be `$scope.$apply` and i don't see why that wouldn't fix it

Comment: Oh, that's it. Tanks alot